# javascript iterate through and map a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to apply a function to each of the values at all levels of the array:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[[1,2],[1,2]],1,2,3]
```

for example, multiply all the values by 3, and map it in the same format as before so I get:

```
arr = [[3,6,9],[3,6,9],[[3,6],[3,6]],3,6,9]
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

I tried to use a recursive function:

```
function mapall(array){
         array.map(function(obj){
                   if (Array.isArray(obj)===true) { return mapall(obj) }
                   else{ return obj*3 }
                   })
            };
```

but when I run it I just get undefined, so I must be doing something not quite right??

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything was working, but you forgot to return from `array.map`. Here's a cleaner version of your code:

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[[1,2],[1,2]],1,2,3];
function mapAll(array){
  return array.map(function(item){
    return Array.isArray(item) ? mapAll(item) : item * 3;
  });
}
alert(JSON.stringify(mapAll(arr)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Version with callback function where you can do with array elements what you want (`el * 2` or something else)

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[[1,2],[1,2]],1,2,3];

function mapAll(array, cb) {
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            mapAll(array[i], cb);
        } else {        
            array[i] = cb(array[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return array;
};

var res = mapAll(arr, function (el) {
    return el * 3;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```